# How to get "Trace image to grease pencil" to work?

Tags: grease-pencil

**The Problem**

I have attempted to use the "Trace image to grease pencil" today and it seems to only return a black square for me, despite the image I want to trace not being a black square.

It seems like it's just not finding the image I want to sketch and is just returning a black nothingness, but I cannot see where I am going wrong as I have the image selected when applying this conversion.

It also a pretty simple feature to understand from some youtube videos, such as this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yz7EZShDvq8&t=37s&ab_channel=StevenScott, as well the blender documentation for this. For which I have followed the very simple instructions to the dot.

**Example of problem**

I am using a pretty basic image as a test for this, it's a very simple black and white UFO type sketch. When I add this image and then attempt to use the conversion feature "Trace image to grease pencil", the black square arrives as you will see in the pictures below.

[image: The image used. A simple black and white sketch]

And here it famously is, the black square

[image: The result of clicking "Trace image to grease pencil]

**Things I have attempted**

- I have attempted to use the same image with a transparent background, black square
- I have attempted to use different image types such as png or jpg, black square
- I have attempted to use different images, colourful images, detailed etc. Black square
- I have attempted to change the image from a reference image to a background image, black square
- I have fiddled with the trace image to grease pencil options window with every combination of settings that can be possibly imagined, black square

Maybe there is an issue here, or it could be that I'm missing something extremely obvious. Though the steps are quite simply to add an image to the scene and then apply this "Trace image to grease pencil" conversion.

Either way any pointers would be a great help

Comment: I had the same issue...I opened the image in affinity designer the resaved it as png...whole document no transparency....then traced it again in blender!...some images will just not work ..

Answer (score 1):

In  *Trace Image to Grease Pencil * change the *Turn Policy* from *Black* to  *White*.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer, when you add the image, please choose the image as background, it will work.